# How do I control the execution order in unioned queries?

Tags: t-sql

I have a series of queries joined by union. Example:

```
SELECT
    SUM(WHOS) [CRITERIA]
FROM ONFIRST

UNION

SELECT
    COUNT(WHATS) [CRITERIA]
FROM ONSECOND

UNION

SELECT
   IDONTKNOW [CRITERIA]
FROM ONTHIRD
```

etc.

The query results don't always come back in the same order and I want the results to be in the same order I have the queries written.

Example: Sometimes I get the SUM of WHOS first, sometimes I get the COUNT of WHATS first.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates so a result row might have come from all of the inputs. Please define the requirements better.

Comment: There are no duplicate values to be removed and each time I run the query I get the same number of results they're just not always in the same order. I'm not sure I understand how to better define the requirements. other than to say I want the top result to be the results of the query I wrote first and the bottom to be the query I write last.

Comment: So sounds like you need `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`.

Comment: @MartinSmith `UNION ALL` still doesn't guarantee the result order, though.

Comment: @Siyual. No I didn't say it did. Order is never guaranteed without Order by. They need `UNION ALL` as it fits their desired semantics. It guarantees each result row maps to only one source query so removes that ambiguity. And is more efficient given they don't want duplicate removal anyway.

Comment: @Siyual thanks for this. It's the best answer I came up with and was hoping there was something simpler. There are a lot of queries joined and was hoping to avoid going back to manually add the dummy order row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this easily by using a dummy order column, and ordering by that value:

```
;With Cte As 
(
    Select  Sum(WHOS) CRITERIA
          , 1 As Ord
    From    ONFIRST
    Union
    Select  Count(WHATS) CRITERIA
          , 2 As Ord
    From    ONSECOND
    Union
    Select  IDONTKNOW CRITERIA
          , 3 As Ord
    From    ONTHIRD
)
Select  CRITERIA
From    Cte
Order By Ord Asc;
```